# Make a random drum loop

Tags: code-golf, random, combinatorics, music

Do randomly generated drum loops sound good?

A **drum loop** is a \$5\times 32\$ matrix \$A\$ of \$1\$s and \$0\$s such that

1. \$A_{1,1}=A_{1,17}=A_{2,9}=A_{2,25}=1\$,
2. for each \$i\$, the \$i\$th row has exactly \$f(i)\$ different \$1\$s, where \$ f(1)=3, f(2)=2, f(3)=6, f(4)=8, f(5)=5\$,
3. for each \$j\equiv 1\bmod 4\$, the \$j\$th column has exactly one \$1\$, and
4. for each \$j\not\equiv 1\bmod 4\$, the \$j\$th column has at most one \$1\$.

Here, the rows provide instructions for each of five drums, with each column representing a beat. In particular, the first row corresponds to a kick, while second row corresponds to a snare.

Write the shortest code that draws a matrix uniformly from the set of drum loops.

Feel free to use your code to draw a random drum loop, implement the drum loop on [this website](https://splice.com/sounds/beatmaker/f12e73c93b97), and then post a link to your creation in your post. (Note that we only use the first 5 rows of this online beat maker.)

**Edit 1:** To be clear, we are using 1-based indexing: the row indices are \$\{1,\ldots,5\}\$ and the column indices are \$\{1,\ldots,32\}\$.

**Edit 2:** Judging by the current submissions, the answer to my original question appears to be "yes": randomly generated drum loops *do* sound good. Here are links to the current examples:

- [Random drum loop by @Arnauld](https://splice.com/sounds/beatmaker/ad842eea5cf7)
- [Random drum loop by @tom](https://splice.com/sounds/beatmaker/b3054cbac7f1)
- [Random drum loop by @KevinCruijssen](https://splice.com/sounds/beatmaker/96d2538ae65b)

Comment: May we output the transposed matrix instead?

Comment: Just to clarify, I am  guessing that you want the code to generate a different drum pattern each time it is run with a different seed value rather than to produce a single 'random' pattern that is the same each time.

Comment: @Arnauld - Yes, you may output the transpose instead.

Comment: @tom - Correct. Each run of the code should produce an independent realization of the random matrix.

Comment: I assume \$i,j\$ are 1-based in your challenge description? It isn't mentioned anywhere whether the 5x32 matrix you describe uses 1- or 0-based indexing, so you might want to add that.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - Good point. I clarified this in my post.

Comment: Can we output a matrix of True and False rather than 1 and 0?

Comment: @NickKennedy - yes.

Comment: Why can't I read "for each i, the ith row has exactly f(i) different 1s" -- what are "different 1s" meant? 1 is always an 1, there is only 1 1 and there can't be any different 1s. Where am I wrong?...

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin - There are exactly f(i) entries in the ith row that equal 1.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>413 394 389 379 378 360 342 327 307 299 298</s> 293 bytes

```c
#define F;for(b[8]=b[v=24]=3,n=0;n
#define B,b[n]==
a[]=L"14444448888888822222",b[32],r[24],n,k,j,t=20,v;main(i){srand(&i)F<v;*b=b[16]=1)r[n++]=n/3-~n F<4;a[k]=a[t])b[i=4+n++*8]=a[k=rand()%t--]-48 F<16;r[j]=r[v])b[r[j=rand()%v--]]=a[n++]-48 F<32;n++)printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n"B 1 B 3 B 4 B 8 B 2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BboMwDIbvfQpE1YmURCshqpBSXzhw2ht4OQQoVcrmTSlih2l79LGkG7/1S7bz@U8nLl23LNv@PDg6J40e3nzWYmWgxRmkMlBygoOmzYrUvEUyABuLBp7SQt1V/UtGpQEppeEeQwAnPvIrn0Ae@KxfraPMsc@bt9RnD441p1nv2/BbcTRQMI@U5wbosRTflDQnpS2OBixOhrXoQOXhfV/FzQj3DLabhDBCVYEujtrj1YDHOeKhX5k5MPEopv@xpdRhYO/e0TRk6a5f65nSOimSOimDVXAVLJn@Wpafbnixl9siPn4B)

```c
#define F;for(b[8]=b[v=24]=3,n=0;n
#define B,b[n]==
a[]=L"14444448888888822222",b[32],r[24],n,k,j,t=20,v;main(i){srand(time(0))F<v;*b=b[16]=1)r[n++]=n/3-~n F<4;a[k]=a[t])b[i=4+n++*8]=a[k=rand()%t--]-48 F<16;r[j]=r[v])b[r[j=rand()%v--]]=a[n++]-48 F<32;n++)printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n"B 1 B 3 B 4 B 8 B 2);}
```

[try it online -earlier algorithm 307 bytes](https://tio.run/##PU/LboMwELznKxBRJAy2CsaKkMxeOHDqiau7B56Rk8atCKKHKP300gU1HWsszeysvduKU9suy77rB@t6r9TDxxg4iLXbPb1KN8Yi1OYCY@26gB0mIVCoTJO1@hPqR5knx/@OgjfGIcCuNgivfqI2ZH@QK3yKpBL5aKRC7viFn/kEMuYzSKWvtXWBZffb9uFkr30QM1bmsw4baExyREjYaFwUIbiXVHw7mjFDKtFrkHplrjS7W1BRFlKo0nStejTn5w4z7aBJI5kzVqHcMp@jddMQ@Ifued6cX3iJV3gpUREzomT6sSw/7fBen26L@PoF)

Many thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat) for more byte savings (360 to 342 - then 342 to 328 and 327 to 307 - then modified algorithm from 328 to 299 and 298 to 293).

Compiles ok without `#include<stdio.h>` using the `-w` compiler flag, thanks to @Arnaud for pointing this out.

As written it generates a fresh sequence each time. If we are allowed manual intervention of a new number in `srand` to generate a different drum sequence with say `srand(6);` then we can save 16 bytes.

Thanks to @Arnaud who made asked the question about generating the transpose matrix, which is what this program does. Thanks also for suggesting the change from `int` to `char` for `a[20]` that saves 15 bytes. Also thanks for @Post Rock Garf Hunter who figured out a way to remove white space near the `B`s and then saved more bytes fixing up the #defines so that `F` is included in `R`. `#define' tokens often seem to need whitespace so they are cleanly identified.

This code works on `tio.run`, but elsewhere may need to include `time.h`.

## How the program works

logic:

- **setup**
- 4 sounds are fixed (at 1,9,17,25)
- remaining sounds to be distributed randomly are in `a[20]`
- `b[32]` holds output - one cell for each beat (1 to 32, but in C of course 0 to 31)
- 4 of the `b` cells must have something (at 5,13,21,29)
- remaining sounds randomly scattered to empty cells
- `r[24]` holds list of empty cells (2,3,4, 6,7,8 etc. in C 0,1,2, 4,5,6 etc.)
- **execute**
- put in 4 fixed sounds
- choose random sound from `a` to put in each of 4 cells with sounds
- choose random cell from `r` to put in random sound from remaining `a` sounds (simplification to algorithm is possible here by putting remaining sounds one by one from 1 to 16 (or 0 to 15) in a random cell, but this gave more bytes..., but now thanks to @ceilingcat this is now smaller see [tio.run link](https://tio.run/##NY1NboMwEIX3OQWiioSDrYKxIiRnNixY9QZTL8xf5JBMKwfRRdUevdSk5Y2eNDP@5rkV57ZdlqeuHxz1Ua2HN580WBpocAapDBScINO025CKN0gGYGfRwEucq4fKf8lVcUAKabjHEMCJj/zCJ5AZn/XNOkoc@7x7S10yuVufZIzVp1kfmvBlfjSQM4@UpgbouRDfFNUnpS2OBixOhjXoQKXh/VCumxEeQWw/CWGEKgOdH7XHiwGP84qHfmPmwKxHa/ofW0gdBvbuHU1DEu@7rV4prqI8qqIiWAWXwZLpr2X5aYerPd8X8fEL) for details)
- print result

this is a long version of the code without the `#define` and other space savers to show the logic, but with small differences e.g. in final version `a` is `char *` not `int *`

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int a[20]={1,4,4,4,4,4,4,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,2,2,2,2,2},
    b[32]={},r[24],n,k,j,t=20,v=24;
  time_t q;srand(time(&q));  
//random initialization

  for(n=0;n<24;n++n=0;n<v;n++)r[n]=n+n/3+1;
// set up r with list of cells that don't definitely have sound 012,456 etc.

  b[0]=b[16]=1;b[8]=b[24]=16;
//put in fixed sounds

  for (n=0;n<4;n++) 
    {k=rand()%t--;b[4+n*8]=a[k];a[k]=a[t];}
//choose a random sound from a to put in each of 4 cells that must  have sound
// each sound selected is then replaced by the sound at the end of the list
// and the length of the list is reduced by one

  for (n=0;n<16;n++) 
    {k=rand()%t--;j=rand()%v--;b[r[j]]=a[k];a[k]=a[t];r[j]=r[v];}
// random cell from remaining `r` cells and random sound are selected 
// again after selection from list final item replaces selected and length
// reduced by one 

  for (n=0;n<32;n++) 
    {printf("%d%d%d%d%d\n",(b[n]==1),(b[n]==16),(b[n]==4),(b[n]==8),(b[n]==2));}
 // print out 0 and 1 from logical tests to print transpose matrix
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Trivial golfing suggestion: remove all the unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: [Suggested optimization](https://tio.run/##TVDLbsIwELzzFVYqqqRxWuJYKJLZHnrgA3p1rSrP4gSWYtxcUL49tUNBXUtjz2jXu7NV8lVV0/Sgsdr/1M3mbGt9fN69Lv4re13OUt20GhvyTkQPpsA6jJY2SUQptYJC9irhufC3I1aJ8V6wJe3RhAgrgZu7@EZoWEpUAAuNlhwKjWF0sfrQfFpyEue5gafh4ymKRLUrDCkkWykIUj5H/hfMR0BLmTEFl5EaybiiSHvaUU0tsBUdgHGxJYPAOI6M74oxvmRx6oZ3P5YyXSvwJPfElUMm3Nh8zr9o4DE@5c74lqTrq9bdNjC4DWgwslPCg3sNas7M2DXz2zh/bRgs69v5wMDZTyMHmQfuIffAnNNxnKZf) for the initialization of `a[]`.

Comment: @PostRockGarfHunter many thanks. I guess that after `)` and `"` the compiler does not get confused by the lack of white space before the `B`.

Comment: Fiddling around with your defines a bit I could [I removed another 10 bytes.](https://tio.run/##TU/LbsIwELzzFVYqqoQ4LXEsFMlsDxz4AK6uVeVFMYGlGDeXKN@e2mlBXWtsz2h37KmSz6oaxyeN1em7btY3W@vLy@Ft9l856XKS6mavsSFbsr@YEGEpcP0Qd6IFU2AdRnObJKKUWkEhW5XwXPjTEavEsCXp6jGzoaVEBTA7FxrDqLf63HxYchW3ycnT8PkaRaI6FIYUki0VBCmfKv8r5itwRhlT0A/USMYVRdrSI9XUAlvSDhgXW9IJjOPI@BcxxtcsTt0vnWMp05UCT3JP3Dhkrp1P7b0GHuMid/kmeryH7FxIDUYelfCbu3Vqt2C/XV9Go92Hwby@r3cMNiQlG5I5cIfcgUViGMbxBw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: The general rule seems to be that gcc needs whitespace between macros and letters or numbers, but not other sorts of characters.  This is a pretty common rule for a lot of languages.

Comment: Probably the last thing I will see but since `F` is always followed by a space removing `<` from the end of its definition, and adding it instead of the space after each use, will actually save 1 byte.

Comment: You can omit `#include<stdio.h>`. You may compile with `-w` (using the _Compiler flags_ section) to get rid of the warnings.

Comment: Here's a link to your creation: https://splice.com/sounds/beatmaker/b3054cbac7f1

Comment: Suggest `&i` instead of `time(0)`

Comment: @ceilingcat - how does that work?... well it does so great... - so I guess that the pointer for `i` is in effect a random number each time the code runs... !! Many thanks again.

Comment: Some platforms, like TIO, have [Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>194 193</s>  189 bytes

Returns \$M^T\$.

```javascript
_=>(g=n=>n?g(/1/.test(c=m[R()*32|0])?n:n-=c[h()]=1):m)(16,a=[1,,6,8,5],R=Math.random,h=_=>a[y=R()*5|0]?a[y]--&&y:h(),m=[...Array(32)].map((_,x)=>(c=[0,0,0,0,0],x&3?0:c[x&7?h():x/8&1]=1,c)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5Ba4NAEIXv/RVCwZ0p4xq1pkGYSH9AL7lul7BsjCboGjYSDPS/203JoczpzXvzzTubm7laf7pMiRsPzXLkZc9baNnx1tUtpFkqp@Y6geVB7QDfivxnpbF2lUvYqg5Qc4bVgJCtybDKiNa0oVLTjr/M1Elv3GEcqOOANerOD0YZEHUQOkni@F4FCA2spJSf3ps7FDlqOZgLwJ5mDG0sqxU9R9McF/WqsmqOP@pwWs3pJs5CC7KIuNjRXce@kf3Ygsjy4r0U@PJ/eQT8g/uIt5GX5/HkQAiUvrn0xjaQyrSl6PZwRfIq1E0jPlPfToQPvw)

### How?

**Note**: *Columns* and *rows* in the following explanation refer to the matrix described in the challenge. They are stored the other way around in this implementation.

#### Initialization

We define an array \$a\$ holding the number of hits that need to be added to each row, ignoring the 4 fixed positions.

```javascript
a = [ 1, , 6, 8, 5 ]
```

We define the helper function \$h\$ that picks a random row among those that are not completely filled, and updates \$a\$ accordingly.

```javascript
h = _ => a[y = R() * 5 | 0] ? a[y]-- && y : h()
```

We define a matrix \$m\$ of \$32\times5\$ filled with \$0\$'s, except the columns such that \$x\equiv 0\pmod 4\$ (using 0-indexing) which are initialized according to the rules described in the challenge.

```javascript
m = [...Array(32)]          // set up 32 columns
  .map((_, x) => (          // for each column at position x:
    c = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],    //   start with all values set to 0
    x & 3 ?                 //   if x mode 4 is not equal to 0:
      0                     //     do nothing
    :                       //   else:
      c[                    //     update c:
        x & 7 ?             //       if x mod 8 is not equal to 0:
          h()               //         use a random row
        :                   //       else:
        x / 8 & 1           //         fixed position: use either row 0 or 1,
                            //         depending on the parity of floor(x / 8)
      ] = 1,                //     set the hit
    c                       //   yield the final column
  ))                        // end of map()
```

#### Main loop

We randomly add the \$16\$ remaining hits on empty columns (which implies \$x\not\equiv 0\pmod 4\$) until all rows are filled.

```javascript
( g = n =>                  // n = total number of hits to add
  n ?                       // if n is not equal to 0:
    g(                      //   do a recursive call:
      /1/.test(             //     test whether
        c = m[R() * 32 | 0] //     a randomly selected column c
      ) ?                   //     contains any '1'; if it does:
        n                   //       just pass n unchanged to try again
      :                     //     else:
        n -= c[h()] = 1     //       set the hit on this column, on a random row
                            //       and decrement n
    )                       //   end of recursive call
  :                         // else:
    m                       //   we're done: return m[]
)(16)                       // initial call to g with n = 16
```

Comment: thanks for the question about M transpose, that was really useful.

Comment: Here's a link to your creation: https://splice.com/sounds/beatmaker/ad842eea5cf7

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I always learn so much from your submissions :)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 65 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
31Ý©8ˆ24ˆ40¯ǝ0ˆ16ˆ®¯KΩˆ48¯¦¦ǝ•Wk¤]•3ôεćи}˜.ržw8и«®¯K.r.¡4Ö}é˜ǝb€¦
```

Outputs as a transposed list of strings.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f2PDw3EMrLU63GZmcbjMxOLT@@FyD022GZqfbDq07tN773EqgqMWh9YeWHVp2fO6jhkXh2YeWxAJp48Nbzm090n5hR@3pOXpFR/eVW1zYcWg1WI9ekd6hhSaHp9UeXnl6zvG5SY@a1hxa9h9IBh/e4XVo938A) (The footer pretty-prints this as the intended rows/columns. Feel free to remove the footer to see the actual result.)

**Explanation:**

```python
31Ý                # Push a list in the range [0,31]
   ©               # Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
8ˆ                 # Add 8 to the global array
  24ˆ              # Add 24 to the global array as well
     40¯ǝ          # Replace the values at the indices of the global array with 40
0ˆ                 # Add 0 to the global array
  16ˆ              # Add 16 to the global array as well
     ®             # Push the [0,31] list from variable `®` again
      ¯K           # Remove all values of the global array (the [0,8,16,24])
        Ω          # Pop and push a random index from this list
         ˆ         # Add it to the global array as well
            ¯¦¦    # Push the global array with the first two (8,24) removed
          48   ǝ   # Replace the values at the remaining three indices with 48
•Wk¤]•             # Push compressed integer 533636834
      3ô           # Split it into parts of size 3: [533,636,834]
        ε          # Map over each integer
         ć         #  Extract head; pop and push remainder and head
          и        #  Repeat the remainder the head amount of times
                   #   i.e. 533 becomes [33,33,33,33,33]
        }˜         # After the map: flatten the list of list of integers
          .r       # And randomly shuffle it
            žw8и   # Then push a list of 8 32s
                «  # And merge it to the end of the list
®                  # Push the [0,31] list from variable `®` again
 ¯K                # Remove all indices stored in the global array
                   # (the [0,8,16,24] and one random index)
   .r              # Randomly shuffle these remaining indices
     .¡            # Group the remaining indices by:
       4Ö          #  Where this (0-based) index is divisible by 4
                   #  (which would be i % 4 == 1 for the corresponding 1-based index)
     }é            # After the group by, sort the two inner lists by length,
                   # so the indices divisible by 4 are before the other indices
       ˜           # And flatten it to a single list
ǝ                  # Then insert the shuffled integers at those shuffled indices
 b                 # Convert each integer to a binary string
                   # (32=100000;33=100001;34=100010;36=100100;40=101000;48=110000)
  €¦               # And then remove the leading "1" from each
                   # (after which the resulting list is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•Wk¤]•` is `533636834`.

Comment: Here's a link to your creation: https://splice.com/sounds/beatmaker/96d2538ae65b

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 43 bytes

```
32s8Zs4ZḢ;FẊḣ⁴ƲƊḢŒœ;FẊ$ƲFṙ-“¥©€Þı‘œṖ;¹Ṭz0ZṖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/YqNgiqtgk6uGORdZuD3d1Pdyx@FHjlmObjgFZi45OOjoZLKpybJPbw50zdR81zDm09NDKR01rDs87svFRw4yjkx/unGZ9aOfDnWuqDKKA7P@HFkUCDX24cy1cCAA)

A niladic link that returns a 32x5 matrix of 1s and 0s representing the drum loop. The footer simply prints it concatenated and separated by newlines.

### Explanation

```
32                                          | 32
  s8                                        | Split into groups of 8
    Z                                       | Transpose
     s4                                     | Split into groups of 4
       Z                                    | Transpose
               Ɗ                            | Following as a monad:
        Ḣ                                   | - Head
         ;    Ʋ                             | - Concatenate to following as a monad:
          F                                 |   - Flatten
           Ẋ                                |   - Shuffle list
            ḣ⁴                              |   - First 16
                       Ʋ                    | Following as a monad:
                Ḣ                           | - Head
                 Œœ                         | - Odd/even indexed items
                   ;  $                     | - Concatenate to:
                    F                       |   - Remainder of list flattened
                     Ẋ                      |   - Shuffled
                        F                   | Flatten
                         ṙ-                 | Rotate right 1 item
                           “¥©€Þı‘œṖ        | Split list before positions 4, 6, 12, 20, 25
                                    ;¹      | Concatenate to 32 (because 32 was the beginning of this niladic link)
                                      Ṭ     | Convert from lists of numeric indices to logical lists with 1s at those positions
                                       z0   | Transpose with 0 as filler
                                         Z  | Transpose
                                          Ṗ | Remove last (the sixth list introduced with the 32 above)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 180 bytes

```python
from random import*
r=range
s=sample
a=s(s([x for x in r(32)if x%4],16)+[x*8+4 for x in r(4)],20)
print([[i in t for i in r(32)]for t in[[0,16,a[0]],[8,24],a[1:7],a[7:15],a[15:]]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYy9CsMgFEZ3n8KloIlDfpsQyJNc7iA0aYVG5epgn96aDKXTx/k4HP@JL2f7nHdyBydtH2XM4R3FitFajufGwhr04d8b02sQQUDiuyOeuLGcRN9Js/N0G1C1d1lDquZ6@BcGiaprJPNkbBQA5rzjZZhfAk@MBQGa0lEaGkQFs@pKV0O7TOdMSzteOC6IKHP@Ag)

Prints a logical matrix representing the drum loop.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>400</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>361</s></sup> 338 bytes

```python
from random import*
r=randrange
p=65537
def h(b=p): 
 while b==p:b=p|1<<r(32)
 l=[b,16777472]
 for i in[6,8,5]:
  while bin(b).count('1')!=i:b=sum(1<<r(32)for j in[1]*i)
  l+=[b]
 return l
g=1
while g:
 l,g=h(),0
 for i in range(32):
  b=sum(j&1<<i!=0for j in l)
  if i%4:g|=b>1
  else:g|=b!=1
for i in l:print(f"{bin(i)[2:]:>032}"[::-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc9Ra4MwEAfw93yKs7A16dwwWnWEpl9EfJht1JQYQ6qMse6zu0uL20MId3C//537mvrRZsvS@nEA/2HP@OnBjX7aES9DA1@niJNFnmclOasWetpIxwQQ@Oy1UdBI6QS2bvxw8DRLGQEjqybmRVmW@zKtCbSjBw3aVkX8Hue1ILDOaksb9nYaZzvRLd@ySGq0rvNAVy3MXsIsr3cabTAvqCPq1TR7C4Z0kpMH16Fs4k72lMXJfyzcjwhYSH7wl2cM0JFMVh9MwHUL@mkvuptsjhxrZa7qXkUY8ucZ4bzGjdvNd7hAsyoVtTgmWfqzqYR45TVbll8)

Full program outputs a \$5\times32\$ matrix of \$1\$s and \$0\$s.  Bit slow at times (\$\sim15\$ seconds), but you can't rush the creative process! :P

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 138 bytes

```r
s=sample
y=s(c(8*0:3+5,s((1:32)[-(4*0:7+1)],16)))
z=matrix(0,5,32)
z[1,c(1,17,y[1])]=z[2,c(9,25)]=z[3,y[2:7]]=z[4,y[8:15]]=z[5,y[16:20]]=1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBCsMgEEX3nmSmmYKjMaYDnkRchNBFoYESu2i8vJ1k997j/733muqyfd5Pc6QKK8w3K34IVAFYvMN8h1FTHBgL8YSIpqVt@e6vH1gKpBPTMtMKTBzpyFywpJadlge5cInX7iSWk0flWThcEs7DJM6qce9/)

A full program that implicitly prints the drum loop as a matrix of 1s and 0s.

## Alternative using a third party package:

### [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + DescTools, 130 bytes

```r
s=sample
y=s(c(8*0:3+5,s((1:32)[-(4*0:7+1)],16)))
sapply(list(c(1,17,y[1]),c(9,25),y[2:7],y[8:15],y[16:20]),DescTools::Unwhich,32)
```

[RDRR it!](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=s%3Dsample%0Ay%3Ds(c(8*0%3A3%2B5%2Cs((1%3A32)%5B-(4*0%3A7%2B1)%5D%2C16)))%0Asapply(list(c(1%2C17%2Cy%5B1%5D)%2Cc(9%2C25)%2Cy%5B2%3A7%5D%2Cy%5B8%3A15%5D%2Cy%5B16%3A20%5D)%2CDescTools%3A%3AUnwhich%2C32))

A full program that implicitly prints a logical matrix (in the transposed form).